# How to receive Dynamic JSON in MVC 5 from another api service

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use a credit card api with a return url that yields Dynamic Json with all the parameters that I need.

But in the receiving MVC Controller, I'm receiving empty data. What am I missing here?

This what I have tried:

1: class built on the Json response:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void PeleCardListener(CreditCardResponse CardResponse)
 {   
    //CardResponse.ResultData.CardHolderEmail null
 }
```

2: string and String

```
 [HttpPost]
 // public void PeleCardListener(String CardResponse)
 public void PeleCardListener(string CardResponse)
 {       
     //CardResponse empty
 }
```

How can I receive Dynamic Json from another api service into MVC?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you able to call this API manually from rest client using json data?

Comment: Yes, i able to send data with credit-card info,but i cant receive  Json back from service to know if transaction is succeed.It is working like listener with the request i send where to return data (url)

Comment: I am bit confused here. The code you shared calls another API and you are not receiving response from it? Or you are not able to return response to the calling client? Or someone is calling your API but you are not getting any data in the request? If these are controller action methods why they are returning void? They should be returning httpresponsemessage

Comment: The code is receiving the Json from Api. the api service send to www.test.com/Mycontrolle/PeleCardListener Json,but i did't receive nothing empty Json